# Is it possible to convert a Wordpress theme to a flat HTML or Django template?

Tags: html, django, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hoping to port a Wordpress theme to Django. The theme is the "Thesis" theme, and it keeps everything in a very convoluted way, at least it seems convoluted if you want to just have a look at the full page. The only way I can see doing it is groking through a rendered page by looking at the source HTML, but its not pretty.

Answer (score 5):

That's actually the most straight-forward way to port any theme from one platform to another.  Create a single page/post/whatever with clearly defined placeholders in the text: [Title] [Content] [Author Name] and so on.  Then copy the source HTML into your favorite text or code editor and begin adding in the code specific to the platform you want to deploy the theme on.

I've seen this done very well when taking themes from one platform *into* WordPress.  It should work just as well taking them out of WordPress, too.  Just be prepared to invest a lot of work in rebuilding the usability on the administrative back-end of things.

Comment: Absolutely. This works very well. The platform code was not available (surprisingly) for the Django Book site. So I just grabbed their TOC page + chapter page + CSS and crafted some new JavaScript to handle the comments. Worked like a charm.